memoir, how to define side subcaptions with memoir?
When I like to have images (or tables) caption on outer side of them, I use the following code:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\sidecapmargin{outer}

\begin{document}
What to do that side captions will apear as subcaptions?
%\newpage
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=44mm}
\begin{sidecaption}{figure A}[fig:a]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{sidecaption}

\medskip
\begin{sidecaption}{figure B}[fig:b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{sidecaption}

\caption{Two sub figures}
\label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    
In figure \ref{fig:1} are subfigures \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b} \dots
\end{document}

which gives:

What I should do, that side captions in above figure will appear as subcaptions numbered by (a) and (b) and will be in text referenced as 1(a) and 1(b), however without additional packages (if possible)?

The following implements the formatting for figures, you can define an analogous environment for tables.
The idea is to define a wrapper environment sidesubfigcaption around sidecaption. This wrapper environment keeps a separate counter for the alphabetic numbering, which is reset with the figure environment. The wrapper furthermore redefines \thefigure to show this number only. To get the full numbering (including the main figure number) as reference, it does not use the label argument of sidecaption but instead redefines \@currentlabel and adds a label inside the wrapper. It redefines \figurename locally to make sure the word Figure is not printed for subsidecaptions. Finally it increases and decreases the main figure counter a few times to have the right number appear at the right time.
Note that the two arguments to sidesubfigcaption (the caption text and the label) are both mandatory so you have to use {}{} (instead of {}[] with the optional label argument in the original sidecaption).
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\newcounter{sidesubfigcapcnt}
\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\setcounter{sidesubfigcapcnt}{0}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sidesubfigcaption}[2]{%
\stepcounter{sidesubfigcapcnt}%
\def\thefigure{(\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt})}%
\stepcounter{figure}%
\def\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}(\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt})}%
\label{#2}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\def\figurename{}%
\begin{sidecaption}{#1}%
}{%
\end{sidecaption}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
What to do that side captions will apear as subcaptions?
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=44mm}
\begin{sidesubfigcaption}{figure A}{fig:a}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{sidesubfigcaption}

\medskip
\begin{sidesubfigcaption}{figure B}{fig:b}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{sidesubfigcaption}

\caption{Two sub figures}
\label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    
In figure \ref{fig:1} are subfigures \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b} \dots

\end{document}



For hyperref you need the set the link identifier \theHfigure to something unique, and a \phantomsection to provide a link target.
\newenvironment{sidesubfigcaption}[2]{%
\stepcounter{sidesubfigcapcnt}%
\def\thefigure{(\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt})}%
\stepcounter{figure}%
\def\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}(\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt})}%
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{s\thechapter.\arabic{figure}\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt}}%
\phantomsection%
\label{#2}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\def\figurename{}%
\begin{sidecaption}{#1}%
}{%
\end{sidecaption}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
}


Thank you very much for your answer. I still tested it in my real document(s) and so far I got desired result. For accepting it I need to finish all tests (document structure is quite complex ...).

It works fina at all circumstances in ma real document. Answer accepted. BTW, in \def\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}(\alph{sidesubfigcapcnt})}% I remove parenthesis
arond  \alph{sidesubfigcapcnt} and get referencing style which I more liked.  I like to achieve the same at use of \subbottom of memoir command but so far didn't succeed to achieve this.. About this I will as new question.

hm, it seems that I accept answer to soon. I had problem with definition when I add hyperref  package I get  warnings: pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.0.1})  has been already used, duplicate ignored. Please help me remedy this warnings.

@Zarko you need to set a separate hyperref counter and link target, see edit.

Now works as charm. Acceptance is already return . Thank you very much!

This uses the subcaption package.  Interestingly, while memoir doesn't load ifoddpage, it seems to use it (automatically).  It takes two runs to handle changes.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outer}{\ifoddpage
  \raggedright
\else
  \raggedleft
\fi}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\sidecapmargin{outer}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sidesubcaption}{\def\@captype{subfigure}%
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,justification=outer}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
What to do that side captions will apear as subcaptions?
%\newpage
    \begin{figure}[p]
    %\checkoddpage% automatic?
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=44mm}
\begin{sidesubcaption}
\begin{sidecaption}{figure A}[fig:a]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{sidecaption}

\medskip
\begin{sidecaption}{figure B}[fig:b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{sidesubcaption}

\caption{Two sub figures}
\label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    
In figure \ref{fig:1} are subfigures \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b} \dots
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your answer (+1). Unfortunately sub caption are wrong side of page (on inner instead of outer),

Added ifoddpage to fix margins and justification.

Now I'm focused to content of my document (textbook). I will check added edits ASAP (in the first spare time).
